# SQL SELECT DISTINCT Not functioning

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a selector where I wish users to only see distinct 'items' from a table. Below I have code to loop through the results. If I change the query to SELECT * it works perfectly fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT set FROM trail ORDER BY category
```

Is DESTINCT depreciated? I can't figure out why it wouldn't work.

I have come here after checking other peoples questions regarding this topic. I Tried adding two columns and that displayed nothing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` is a reserve word and so needs escaping like below. Moreover, refrain yourself from using any reserve word (or) key word as your table column name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `set` FROM trail ORDER BY category
```

Comment: That has fixed it thank you! Quick question if you're still around. Using DISTINCT seems to only provide data for that collumn. However I am trying to show/echo the user the: 'Catergory :: set'. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: @Bjaeg, Yes include both the column saying *select distinct category, `set`*